# Thymeleaf concatenation preprocessing:

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, preprocessor

I hope someone can help me with my problem with Thymeleaf.

The case is that I need to do preprocessing with thymeleaf, the first one does it correctly, but inside that first preprocessing I need to get another field from the model, but when I add the field preprocessinf inside another preprocessing it gives me a type error

**Could not parse as expression: "$ {rules ["**

If I do this, it works fine

```
rules[__${row.index}__].propertiesValues[]
```

Failure to insert the other preprocessing

```
rules[__${row.index}__].propertiesValues[__${rules[__${row.index}__].bookingRuleDescriptor.propertyDescriptors[__${iter.index}__].name}__]
```

I hope you can help me.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one preprocessing pass.  You get that error because of the mismatched `__`. For example, the first time it tries to preprocess:

```
propertiesValues[__${rules[__${row.index}__]
```

The expression it tries to evaluate is `__${rules[__`, which is not a valid thymeleaf expression.

The options you have are:

1) If this expression is not being used in a th:field, you shouldn't be doing preprocessing anyways.  You can simply use:

```
${rules[row.index].propertiesValues[rules[row.index].bookingRuleDescriptor.propertyDescriptors[iter.index].name]}
```

2) If you are using this in a th:field, you'll have to use th:with to evaluate some of your expressions before hand.  Something like:

```
<th:block th:with="i=${row.index}, j=${rules[row.index].bookingRuleDescriptor.propertyDescriptors[iter.index].name}">
  <input type="text" th:field="*{rules[__${i}__].propertiesValues['__${j}__']}" />
</th:block>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! @Metroids, the second solution I have implemented and everything is perfect! :)

It is unknown how to create and assign variables in thymeleaf. Thank you for your invaluable help.