# Does thymeleaf support dynamic model attribute names?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to access a specific model attribute value which name depends on an element value coming from the loop which I am iterating over.

Does thymeleaf supports something like this:

```
<p th:if="${'somePrefix_' + ${entry.key}} != null">Write if condition is met.</p>
```

Comment: If you want to convert `${entry.key}` to its value before you concatenate it with the prefix, then you can use [Thymeleaf preprocessing](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#preprocessing). For example: `${'somePrefix_' + __${entry.key}__}`.

Comment: See also [Thymeleaf concatenation preprocessing:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46000447/thymeleaf-concatenation-preprocessing) and similar questions & answers for more examples.